# Downloading disaggregated prices and weights for the US

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, consumption, price-level

For a thesis, I would have to download disaggregated price indices for the US.

I managed to download disaggregated Prices from the [BEA](https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?reqid=19&step=2#reqid=19&step=2&isuri=1&1921=survey).
However, the weights are not included.

I could also download historical weights from the [BLS](https://www.bls.gov/cpi/tables/relative-importance/home.htm#RIData)

The problem is that the descriptions do not match.

Ideally, it would be possible to download the prices and weights by their "CUUR0000SA0" type code but on a disaggregated level.

Anybody have an idea where I could find this?

Thanks!